# install meld on mac lion with macport

Tags: macos, osx-lion, meld

i have succesfully installed meld with macport but after launch meld says:

```
Last login: Tue Aug 27 21:28:07 on ttys001
/opt/local/bin/meld ; exit;
iMac-di-Eros:~ Eros$ /opt/local/bin/meld ; exit;
Couldn't bind the translation domain. Some translations won't work.
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gobject/__init__.py:115: Warning: attempting to add an interface (GtkEditable) to class (HistoryFileEntry) after class_init
  type_register(cls, namespace.get('__gtype_name__'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/meld", line 138, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/local/bin/meld", line 129, in main
    from meld.meldapp import app
  File "/opt/local/lib/meld/meld/meldapp.py", line 199, in <module>
    app = MeldApp()
  File "/opt/local/lib/meld/meld/meldapp.py", line 113, in __init__
    self.prefs = preferences.MeldPreferences()
  File "/opt/local/lib/meld/meld/preferences.py", line 265, in __init__
    super(MeldPreferences, self).__init__("/apps/meld", self.defaults)
  File "/opt/local/lib/meld/meld/util/prefs.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._gconf.add_dir(rootkey, gconf.CLIENT_PRELOAD_NONE)
glib.GError: Contatto col server di configurazione non riuscito; tra le possibili cause la mancanza o l'errata configurazione del demone del bus di sessione D-Bus. Consultare http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ per ulteriori informazioni (dettagli -  1: Recupero delle connessione alla sessione non riuscito: Session D-Bus not running. Try running `launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist'.).
logout
```

this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

does not work

any help?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

launching from command line:

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist
```

did the trick